# Function "if" in edit text

Tags: java, android

I am making application where user have to enter 6 information about him. And These six pieces of information consist of two sections when first three are first section and rest three are second. And here is my question. It is possible that when user put 0 in first edit text and then application goes to second section?. Those 2 section are in one activty. ( Hope you understand everything.Because I don't quite know how to describe my problem myself)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btn1;
EditText et1;
EditText et2;
EditText et3;
EditText et4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btn1;
EditText et1;
EditText et2;
EditText et3;
EditText et4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(s.tostring().equals("0")){
                    et2.requestFocus();
                 }
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok. Its working but for for each number and I only want 0 to jump

Comment: It is possible to do this but with button? If you out 0 application 
will mark the button to move to the next page

Answer (score 0):

You can use listener to Edittext change text event and when user enter some character
call the function.

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // you can call or do what you want with your EditText here
            // yourEditText... 
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
    });
```

Comment: Not completely understand. Could you explain it? I want to make app when in first edit tex when you put 0 and click "-> " you will go to third edit text.

Comment: you can use this listener for edit text 1 and check user input characters if is '0' request focus to edit text 2.
`edittext2.requestFocus()`

Comment: `et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    et2.requestFocus();
   }
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
  });
    }`